# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.jbox2d.collision.AABB

Tags: android, eclipse-plugin

I am trying to run this project but getting above error, project source is here
http://www.bayninestudios.com/2010/04/box2d-on-android/

but this code is run in my friends pc.so I don't know where is the error.

I use eclipse Version: Helios Service Release 2 same my friend use. and also set compiler compliance level : 1.6.

that is not only one project where I got this type of error, but some other project also there which is completely run of my friends pc but not run on my PC.

any buddy face this type of error.

**LogCat error is below.**

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.jbox2d.collision.AABB
at com.bayninestudios.box2ddemo.PhysicsWorld.createWorld(PhysicsWorld.java:28)
at com.bayninestudios.box2ddemo.ClearRenderer.<init>(Box2dDemo.java:224)
at com.bayninestudios.box2ddemo.ClearGLSurfaceView.<init>(Box2dDemo.java:99)
at com.bayninestudios.box2ddemo.Box2dDemo.onCreate(Box2dDemo.java:44)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1072)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1794)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1851)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:132)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1038)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4277)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Force finishing activity com.bayninestudios.box2ddemo/.Box2dDemo
```

Comment: what code is at Line **44** Box2dDemo.java?

Comment: bellow is code at line 44 in Box2dDemo.java 
mGLView = new ClearGLSurfaceView(this, (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE));
but you think herry that is matter for getting error, this code is completely running without any change for my friends PC. you can also try download code and run it. it may be working for you. from above link you can download source code. thanks

Comment: Clean your project and may be remove build path for jar and again give it.

Comment: @HiteshDhamshaniya  Can you come to http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5098/android-people  chat room

Answer (score 3):

Check if your **jar** files is inside of **lib** folder if it so create another folder as **libs** and put all you jar files.

**Delete lib folder** and again add all you jars in your project from **libs** in

Build Path-> Configure Build path ->Select  Java Build path from Left Pane -> Add Jars

Answer (score 1):

step 1: If the code is from an existing project, try to import the project through "new-other-Android-android project from existing code" instead of "import-existing projects into workspace". The first method could create a directory "Android Dependencies" in the project, but the second method maybe not.

step 2: create a new directory such as "lib" in the preject, copy the jbox2d.jar file there. Then, add the jar to your project through the project's right click menu "properties-java build path-libraries-add jars"(delete the error one firstly of course). clean the project and try to run.

step 3: If it is still not working through the above two steps. create **another new** directory other than the previous one called "lib" under the project, you can name it such as "libs". then copy the jar file to "libs", delete "lib" and introuce jar under "libs" to the project just as step2 does. In my case, it is working through **re-introucing** the jar through a new directory.

Anyway, there should be directory "Android Dependencies", jbox2d.jar and annotations.jar should be under the directory finally.

Answer (score 0):

I think reason that your project is not running it's because of `org.jbox2d.collision.AABB` .Class `AABB` is not found in .So please check that you have properly give Build path for jar in project.Check that this `jbox2d-2.0.1-full.jar` path is given in java build path for libraries.

Comment: I find the following ADT Version.
Under Installed Software:
Android Development Tools -- 17.0.0.v201203161636-291853

Under Configuration contents:
Android Development Tools -- 12.0.0.v201106281929-138431