# NoClassDefFoundError or how do I merge two JAR libraries?

Tags: java, android

I have build a library which itself contains another library ( a jar file in its libs folder ), yet when I export my library as a jar file and try to use it in another project, it throws me a NoClassDefFoundError error.

Apparently when exporting my jar file, it doesn't include the other jar file that already was there. What do you think would be the best way to fix that?

I saw http://code.google.com/p/jarjar/wiki/GettingStarted , yet couldn't really understand how do I use it in my case?

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10275853/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-jbox2d-collision-aabb/10278935#10278935

Comment: Did you add it to the Build path? Add it to a directory called 'libs' (do not change this name), and add it to the referenced libraries. They should show up in the 'referenced libraries' and 'android dependencies'

Comment: The answer is on the post of @Venky. Otherwise, you can find more info here: http://tools.android.com/recent/dealingwithdependenciesinandroidprojects

Comment: Yes, of course, I have already done this. And my library ( with a jar in the libs folder ) did work well with other projects, when I had added it as a library. The problem arises when I export it to jar.